# Working with compounds of libraries

Tags: clojure, namespaces, libraries

Often I find myself in a situation when I need to intertwine functionality of two or three libraries. These compound functions are used in a manner similar to a library themselves. About 60% of calls to this library group go to pure libraries and about 40% of calls to the compound. So here comes a question - how do I better organize the code? The diagram below illustrates the matter:

[image: a diagram]

In an OOP language, say, Java, I would simply make a class for that. But in Clojure a dedicated namespace looks like an overkill, esp that there could be many of them, and copy-pasting these compound calls just smells. Anyone has any idea on how to handle this situation gracefully?

Comment: If you can group the functions in a namespace based on what they are used for and what they do, why would that be an overkill? IMHO, when in OOP world, a class seems more of an overkill if all you wan't to do is group some helper functions together.

Comment: @juan.facorro well, yes, I too think like that, but a sight of tens of such "auxiliary" namespaces frightens me. Or maybe I think that namespaces are not usually used for that.. I think I just do not know how to group and name them. How would you group them and give them names if potentially you had, say 100 of them in the system?

Comment: Is this what you're asking about? "Sharing functions between namespaces in Clojure:" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580807/sharing-functions-between-namespaces-in-clojure

Comment: @noahlz interesting post and it definitely gave me some insight on Clojure, but nope, the topic is different. In my case I combine functions from various libraries into greater functions, like molecules from atoms. While atoms retain their identity and importance within the molecule, what I want to deal with - is the compound molecule of my design. Say, lib-1 has `fun-1`, `fun-2` and lib-2 has `fun-a` and `fun-b`, now I make my own fun, which ties all the four together like `(defn fun-1 [x] (fun-1 (fun-a x (fun-b) (fun-2)) x))`. Lots of them, and they are of library nature too.

Comment: I vote "just create a namespace for that." What you described sounds like what many frameworks do, such as Ring, Compojure, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you shouldn't think about your functions in terms of where the code they call lives, but rather of the purposes they serve.

Of course, as you group functions serving a similar purpose in a namespace, you may well find that they tend to be built on top of functions from lib1, lib2 and lib3, but then perhaps not every one uses all those libraries, some might further use lib4 and some will be built without any direct use of the libN by calling your own previously written functions; still, the grouping is correct as long as your namespace maintains its focus.

On the other hand, if you use lib1, lib2 and lib3 for two unrelated purposes (perhaps because those libraries are themselves somewhat on the multipurpose side), then there's no point in grouping the functions serving those unrelated purposes in a single place (whether a namespace or not).

So, just keep the functions (macros etc.) serving a similar purpose together to maintain a clean design in your own codebase. Whether this causes calls into particular libraries to be grouped together or not is not something you should be concerned about.